# How to see PDF content on same view (layout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am able to read pdf file, but I have one problem

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button OpenPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    OpenPDF.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    { 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            File pdfFile = new File("/sdcard/Test.pdf"); 
            if(pdfFile.exists()) 
            {
                Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
                Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                try
                {
                    startActivity(pdfIntent);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(PDFTest.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                }
            }

        }
    });

    }
```

Am using the above code, when I click Button it takes me to another view where PDF content is visible. I dont want to use two activities. But I want to see the pdf content on same view. How to do that. How to stop navigating to next view.
My XML file is:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:text="Button" 
android:id="@+id/button" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
`
```

Can anyone help me on this context.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Library not an Intent.
Try the open source library [muPDF](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf-android/)

Comment: But the code is not in SVN. Any alternative approach to this? I am able to view the pdf file but wants to open in same activity.Just Below that Button.

Comment: What has SVN to do with this? You open a PDF with fire up an Intent to open the PDF in another Program (e.g. Adobe, Aldiko). If you want to show the PDF directly in your Application you need to Render it by yourself.